# function overloading C++

Tags: c++

```
typedef int INT;

1.void f(int x);
2.void f(INT x);

3.g(char (*) [10]);
4.g(char [5] [10]);
```

both the overloads of `f` can exist!
both the overloads of `g` can exist!

can we overload these functions in a class? As 1,3 in base class and 2,4 in derived class.

Comment: looks like a homework question :p

Comment: looks like two questions

Comment: Also, what happened when you simply _tried it_?

Comment: Uhhh... I thought "what's the heck! How can it be?". When you ask a question, don't present it as if it works, unless you have tried it actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
both the overloads of `f` can exist?
```

NO, INT underlying type is `int` thus both `f` has same function signature. which breaks C++

```
both the overloads of g can exist?
```

NO. array decays into pointer, thus `char [5] [10])` turns to  `char (*) [10]` which are same types.

The important rule of function overload is that functions have different signatures which need functions to have different parameter list(parameter type or number).

See Sample code: [link](http://ideone.com/RSfPZt)

Comment: They would be invalid redefinitions if there was a body, but in this case they are valid redeclaration of pre-existing functions (not overloads).

Comment: if just declaration, both f/g are ok, you can even do `void f(int x); void f(int x);`